# Error al crear proyecto de reportes en Visual Studio error: Excepción de HRESULT: 0x8007000D

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rdlc

espero estén bien, tengo un problema y nada mas no logro dar con la solución espero ustedes me puedan auxiliar.
estoy intentando crear un proyecto nuevo en Visual Studio, un **Sitio Web de informes ASP.NET con C#** todo bien hasta ahi, ya agregue el **RDLC** para que me salga esa opción (Sitio Web de informes...) pero al momento de darle en crear me sale este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya reinstale el IDE y todo lo que conlleva este, pero me sigue dando error, espero ustedes me puedan ayudar.